# How to use a do-while loop WITHIN A SWITCH-CASE STRUCTURE in C/C++ to restart a program from the beginning?

Tags: c, switch-statement, do-while

In this multiplication game, I have to generate two random numbers and multiply them. The user has to guess the right product. After the game, the user has a choice to either restart the game or quit (along with other choices to display/reset stats). I am required to use a switch-case structure for the choices the user decides on after the game. I also know I have to use a do-while loop for restarting/quitting the game but **I don't know what to put in place of the bolded comments (after cases 1 and 3)**. Thanks in advance for taking the time to read. Any help is much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {

//Start do-while loop
do {

//Display rules of the game to the user.
printf("Two random numbers (1-12) will be generated and displayed. The objective of this game is to correctly guess the product of the numbers.");

//Generate two random integers between 1 and 12 and display them to the user
int i;
int n1;
int n2;
srand(time(NULL));
for(i = 1; i<=12;i++)
{
 n1 = 1 + rand() % 12; 
 n2 = 1 + rand() % 12;
 printf("The two random numbers generated are : %d and %d\n", n1,n2);
}

//Prompt the user to enter the product of the two numbers
int a;
printf("Enter the product of the two numbers: ");
scanf("%d", &a);

//Determine and display if or not the answer was right
int countCorrect;
int countIncorrect;
int product = n1*n2;
if (a == product)
{
printf("Correct response!");
countCorrect++;
}
else 
{
printf("Incorrect response, the correct answer is: %d\n", product);
countIncorrect++;
}

//Start switch-case structure for post-game options
int choice;
switch (choice)
{
case 1:
printf("You have chosen to play again");
**//How do I restart the program so the user can play again?**
break;

case 2:
printf("You have chosen to see statistics");
printf("The number of correct answers are: %d\n", countCorrect);
printf("The number of incorrect answers are: %d\n", countIncorrect);
break;

case 3:
printf("You have chosen to reset statistics");
countCorrect = 0;
countIncorrect = 0;
break;

case 4:
printf("You have chosen to quit");
**//How do I quit the program?**
break;

default:
printf("Invalid number! Please enter a number from 1 to 4.");
break;
}
}
```

Comment: Put it in a function, return on exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things that need to be fixed. When declaring variables, it's good practice to initialise them at the time of decleration. Rather than `int a; a = x;` And to only declare variables when needed. But this can obviously come down to preference and practice. In C89 variables had to be declared at the top of the scope but I can tell you're not compiling C89. You also didn't need to loop the rand 12 times. Just two calls is enough if you want two seperate ints. Keep in mind rand isn't very good but for practice it's okay. Placing a new line after print statement can make the output neater. `countCorrect` and `countIncorrect` were declared but not initialised to 0 then later incremented. This is bad practice because you don't know the initial value of either variable and you wouldn't get an accurate count.
I'm assuming you want to only quit when the user enters 4 but keep looping otherwise?
Place the switch outside the loop then after the user guesses the product, read the choice from the user and use that value the end of the do while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int guess(){
    int x = 1+rand()%12;
    int y = 1+rand()%12;

    printf("The two random numbers generated are : %d and %d\n", x,y);
    printf("Enter the product of the two numbers: ");
    int z = 0;
    scanf("%d", &z);
    if(z == (x*y)){
        printf("Correct response!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Incorrect response, the correct answer is: %d\n", x*y);
    return 0;
}
int main () {
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Two random numbers (1-12) will be generated and displayed. The objective of this game is to correctly guess the product of the numbers.\n");
    int correct = 0;
    int incorrect = 0;
    int choice = 1;
    do{
        if(choice==1){
            if(guess()){

                ++correct;
            }else{
                ++incorrect;
            }
        }
        printf("Enter 1 to play again\nEnter 2 to see statistics\nEnter 3 to reset statistic\nEnter 4 to quit:");

        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("You have chosen to see statistics\n");
                printf("The number of correct answers are: %d\n", correct);
                printf("The number of incorrect answers are: %d\n", incorrect);
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("You have chosen to reset statistics\n");
                correct = 0;
                incorrect = 0;
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("You have chosen to quit\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid number! Please enter a number from 1 to 4.\n");
                break;
        }
    }while(choice !=4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and help!! This code worked! Creating an int guess () function at the beginning was smart (I never thought of doing that). Much appreciated!